# Any shorter way to solve trigonometric problem?

Tags: trigonometry

If $10 \sin^4\theta + 15 \cos^4 \theta=6$, then find value of $27 \csc^2 \theta + 8\sec^2 \theta$

I know the normal method o solve this problem in which we need to multiply L.H.S. of $10 \sin^4\theta + 15 \cos^4 \theta=6$ by $(\sin^2\theta + \cos \theta^2)^2$ and then simplifying it. It is kind of simplification in which we can commit silly mistakes.

So, is there any shorter way to solve this trigonometric problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\sin^2 \theta =s=1-c$

Then $10s^2+15(1-s)^2=6$ or $25s^2-30s+9=0$ which reduces to $(5s-3)^2=0$

This gives you $s$, and all you need is $s$ and $c$ to compute the original expression.

Comment: Ok thank you so much. This type of question is usually asked in 4 marks MCQ. So one mistake can cost 4 marks.

Answer (score 2):

Following your way:

$$10 \sin^4\theta + 15 \cos^4 \theta=6(\sin^2\theta + \cos \theta^2)^2$$

$$\iff4(\sin^2\theta)^2-12\sin^2\theta\cos^2\theta+9(\cos^2\theta)^2=0$$

Dividing either sides by $\cos^4 \theta,$

$$4(\tan^2\theta)^2-12\tan^2\theta+9=0\iff(2\tan^2\theta-3)^2=0$$

We can find $\sec^2\theta=1+\tan^2\theta, \cot^2\theta=\dfrac1{\tan^2\theta},\csc^2\theta=1+\cot^2\theta$

Hope you can take it home from here

Comment: @hey, Is it short enough?

Comment: Yes(+1), shorter then my method. But not as short as Mark's answer!

Answer (score 1):

How can $20\sin^2\theta + 15\cos^2\theta = 6$? $20\sin^2\theta + 15 \cos^2\theta = 15 + 5\sin^2\theta$, implying that $5 \sin^2\theta = -9$, but $\sin^2\theta$ should be nonnegative.

Comment: I am really sorry. Please check out i have edited question.